# PHP Script Not Running in WordPress Correctly

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I recently converted http://usborrow.pizzli.com/apply to a WordPress Page Template for a site. Every other page came out fine, but when I go to http://usborrow.pizzli.com/?page_id=6, the page seems to lose all of its styling. Any support would be appreciated.

Comment: All links are coming from wordpress however for this particular link "http://usborrow.pizzli.com/?page_id=6" its showing as it is generating from the .net language. If its a site up gradation check if somewhere static URL is causing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's an issue with the relative URL reference. Rather than referencing to the stylesheet with

```
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Try absolute path instead

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This should work on all pages, assuming that you store the stylesheet file inside the css folder within the site root folder. You should also do the same thing with the other CSS for IE

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie7below.css" /><![endif]-->
```

This way, no matter how deep the path the user is accessing (e.g http://usborrow.pizzli.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/file.abc) the CSS can be referenced without any problem.

Comment: Just changed that and it still looks the same

Comment: No, you're doing it wrong. Notice the leading forward slash in the `href` attribute in the code I posted. That's what makes it an absolute path.

Comment: Just tried the <!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie7below.css" /><![endif]-->
 and it doesn't seem to help

Comment: I switched to using the absolute paths. I don't think the JavaScript is loading?

Comment: Is `/apply/` a directory? If so, then you must also include the appropriate path to the file.

Comment: Using /apply/css/style.css made the backgrounds appear. It seems the JavaScript isn't loading, but I don't see anything missing

Comment: Make sure you're selecting the right elements. I notice step 1 is wrapped within an element with the `id` of `fstep-1` but in JavaScript you're selecting `$('#step-1')` with jQuery. Unless I was looking at the wrong code, that'd be the problem.

Comment: The regular steps are below the Fsteps

Comment: Ah, apparently the browser failed to load the Masked Input jQuery plugins, and it stops JavaScript execution when it encounters a call to the plugins inside `apply/js/form.js`. So, try to fix that one and see if it fixes the whole thing.

Comment: I got rid of the apply/js/form.js and it got rid of the yellow stars. How do I get Masked Input jQuery plugin to work?

Comment: Well it seems to be under the `apply` directory, so prepend `apply` to the `href` attribute of the `script` tag.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you should include */apply/style.css*.