# JQuery Script Not Working Correctly in WordPress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Script Not Running in WordPress Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551489/php-script-not-running-in-wordpress-correctly)

I recently converted http://usborrow.pizzli.com/apply to a WordPress Page Template for a site. Every other page came out fine, but when I go to http://usborrow.pizzli.com/?page_id=6, the page seems to be messed up and JavaScript is not being used. Any support would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing one of your javascript files:

GET http://usborrow.pizzli.com/js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js 404 (Not Found)

Looks like (according to your first link)

that it should be:

```
<script src="/apply/js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Just added that. It still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Try it with the URL above (edited)

Comment: Still has the same issue

Comment: you forgot the forward slash "/" before apply

Answer (score 0):

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://usborrow.pizzli.com/js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js

Which makes Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'mask' form.js line 2.

This javascript error stops all other js from being run.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that you are loading jquery two times one in header and one in iframe header. Which causes instantiation of jquery and losses all prev scripts which you are loading for some special purpose.
Is there any special reason of using iframe? if it is not then try to remove it and then check the results.